# Improving remake of primary key performance

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, amazon-rds, alter-table

I'm using a MySQL 5.7 hosted on AWS that has a table with about 500,000,000 rows and 124GB in size.

I want to drop the existing primary key (id) and create a new composite primary key of 2 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2);
```

I have already done this query in a testing environment with the same data, and it works fine.

The problem is that running those 2 queries took over 20 hours, and that is unacceptable in a production scenario.

The way I understand it, InnoDB runs these queries by creating a copy of the table (tmp table) and applying the changes to it - and swapping that table.

I've tried scaling it to a `db.m5.24xlarge` instance, in the hope that the 384GB memory would allow InnoDB to store the entire tmpTable in memory, but it's not working very well - it seems the like the memory is not being utilized.

I have also set the following configuration values:

```
tmp_table_size = 18446744073709551615;
max_heap_table_size = 1844674407370954752;
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size = 184467440737095;
```

Comment: That is not what temp tables are for.  The `ALTER` still needs to read all 126GB and rewrite it to disk, no matter what method is invented.  Plus there needs to be either a sort or a random read/write because the order of the file is different.  2 ALTERs means twice the work; combine then to get it down to 10 hours.  (Alas.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/index.html).

This will allow for no downtime and you can pause it in the middle of a production period

Provided you have twice as much space free (at least 248GB)

### STEP 01 : Select Folder

For this example, let's choose /home/whoeveriam/online_change

```
mkdir -p /home/whoeveriam/online_change
cd /home/whoeveriam/online_change
```

### STEP 02 : Create local my.cnf

```
vi mysql_creds.cnf
```

The contents of `mysql_creds.cnf` should be

```
[client]
host     = (RDS Endpoint)
user     = blahblahblah
password = blahblahblahblahblahblah
```

### STEP 03 : Create Dry Run Script

Create a file called Dry_Run.sh with this

```
BASE_FOLDER=(select absolute path)
MYCNF=$BASE_FOLDER}/mysql_creds.cnf
MYSQL_AUTH="--defaults-file=${MYCNF}"
cd ${BASE_FOLDER}

DB=mydb (put your DBName here)
TB=mytable (put your tablename here)
DBTB="${DB}.${TB}"

OPER=Change ; PHASE=Before ; STEP=DryRun ; EXEC_TYPE=--dry-run
RUNLOG=${BASE_FOLDER}/${TB}-${OPER}-${STEP}.log
ERRLOG=${BASE_FOLDER}/${TB}-${OPER}-${STEP}.err
SCTLOG=${BASE_FOLDER}/${TB}-${OPER}-${PHASE}.log
[ -f ${RUNLOG} ] && echo -e "\nAlready Executed" && cat ${RUNLOG} && exit

PAUSE_FILE=${BASE_FOLDER}/pause.txt
PTOSC_OPTS1="--recursion-method=none"
PTOSC_OPTS1="${PTOSC_OPTS1} --pause-file=${PAUSE_FILE}"
PTOSC_OPTS2="${PTOSC_OPTS2} --max-load      Threads_running=100,Threads_connected=500"
PTOSC_OPTS2="${PTOSC_OPTS2} --critical-load Threads_running=200,Threads_connected=1000"

ALTER_TABLE_STMT="DROP PRIMARY KEY,ADD PRIMARY KEY(column1, column2)"

T1=`date +%s`
pt-online-schema-change ${PTOSC_AUTH} D=${DB},t=${TB} ${PTOSC_OPTS1} --alter "${ALTER_TABLE_STMT}" ${PTOSC_OPTS2} ${EXEC_TYPE} >${RUNLOG} 2>${ERRLOG}
T2=`date +%s`
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} -ANe"SHOW CREATE TABLE ${DBTB}\G" > ${SCTLOG}

SQL="SET @t1=${T1}; SET @t2=${T2}; SELECT"
SQL="${SQL} FROM_UNIXTIME(@t1) ${STEP}_Initiated"
SQL="${SQL},FROM_UNIXTIME(@t2) ${STEP}_Completed"
SQL="${SQL},SEC_TO_TIME(@t2 - @t1) ${STEP}_RunTime"
mysql ${MYSQL_AUTH} --table -Ae"${SQL}" >> ${RUNLOG}
cat ${RUNLOG}
```

### STEP 04 : Create Live Run Script

```
cp Dry_Run.sh Live_Run.sh
```

Change the line that has

```
OPER=Change ; PHASE=Before ; STEP=DryRun ; EXEC_TYPE=--dry-run
```

to

```
OPER=Change ; PHASE=After ; STEP=LiveRun ; EXEC_TYPE=--execute
```

### STEP 05 : Start up Linux Screen Session

```
screen -S BigChange
```

### STEP 06 : Execute Dry Run

```
chmod +x Dry_Run.sh
./Dry_Run.sh
```

### STEP 07 : Execute Live Run

```
chmod +x Live_Run.sh
./Live_Run.sh
```

### FINAL NOTES

If you wish pause the change in the middle of Production Time, run this

```
cd /home/whoeveriam/online_change
touch pause.txt
```

It will pause whether it is. Incoming changes will be handled by the triggers

When you want to continue, remove the file

```
cd /home/whoeveriam/online_change
rm pause.txt
```

You can monitor progress in the Log and Error Files

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The tool won't let you do anything with `PRIMARY KEY` unless you specify the `--no-check-alter` option. I also needed to specify the `--no-check-unique-key-change` to get it to work - but it's running now at a pace of 4000 rows per minute. The table has 500000000 rows so thats 86 days. Do you have any ideas to speed this process up?